# Postgres to_timestamp function

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, to-timestamp

I have a python script that insert hourly readings into a postgres db. It is failing in 2010-03-28. How is postgres interpreting both 01:00:00 and 02:00:00 as 02:00:00. what am I doing wrong (ps: works for other dates prior to this)

```
 select to_timestamp('28/03/2010 01:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2010-03-28 02:00:00+01
(1 row)

select to_timestamp('28/03/2010 02:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2010-03-28 02:00:00+01
(1 row)
```

Comment: I fail to reproduce this behavior in postgresql 12. I suggest you fold both selects into a single one and check the output ( `select to_timestamp('28/03/2010 01:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') one, to_timestamp('28/03/2010 02:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') two, version() v;` ). The query also informs about the postgresql version you are running.

Comment: In which timezone is your server? It might be related to DST switching (although that happens at 02:00, not at 01:00

Answer (score 0):

> what am I doing wrong?

Nothing wrong.

As commented by a_horse_with_no_name, what you are seeing is the effect of Daylight Saving Time. On 2 AM CET on March 28th, the clock skips one hour and goes directly to 3 AM. I assume that your timezone is `UTC+01`, so you are seeing this on 1 AM > 2 AM.

That particular day only has 23 hours: both dates do represent the same point in time, which is what you are seeing in the results generated by `to_timestamp()`.

Extracting the corresponding epochs, you can also see that the results are identical:

```
select 
    to_timestamp('28/03/2010 01:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "1 AM",
    to_timestamp('28/03/2010 02:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "2 AM",
    extract(epoch from to_timestamp('28/03/2010 01:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) "1 AM epoch",
    extract(epoch from to_timestamp('28/03/2010 02:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) "2 AM epoch"
```

```
1 AM                   | 2 AM                   | 1 AM epoch | 2 AM epoch
:--------------------- | :--------------------- | :--------- | :---------
2010-03-28 02:00:00+01 | 2010-03-28 02:00:00+01 | 1269738000 | 1269738000
```

This is just one of the many tricks involved when working with dates. There is not much you can do about that from Postgres' perspective: it is on your application to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I disagree with the statement that you're doing nothing wrong.

If your database timezone is set to a timezone thats changes to daylight savings at 01:00 on 2010-03-28, e.g., 'Europe/London', then you shouldn't be attempting to create records for both 01:00:00 and 02:00:00 on 2010-03-28, as 01:00:00 does not exist (the time jumps from 00:59:59 to 02:00:00).

If you're not meant to be following daylight savings, then you need to change the DB server timezone to one that doesn't, e.g., 'GMT' or 'UTC'.